# How to count all the active products in magento

Tags: magento

I want to count all the active products from magento backend. All the products that are in the backend not for particular category, I need all the products .I have a script that not working properly.
my script is :-

```
<?php
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')          
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);

    echo $collection->count();
?>
```

Please suggest me , how can i do.

Comment: Use $collection->getSize()

Comment: @Mufaddal 
it's working, but need to count all categories and sub-categies product.

Comment: I need to count all the active products for all categories and sub-categories.